# React Component JSON Callback Scope

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

I'm using [generator-react-webpack](https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack) to create a React web app. This web app relies on JSON feeds - one of which is hosted on a CDN that does not support JSONP and the CDN url is a subdomain of the webapp. Is there any way to return the JSON data from within the React Component?

**Basic React Component:**

```
var AppComponent = React.createClass({
    loadData: function() {
        jQuery.getJSON(jsonFile.json?callback=?)
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }.bind(this));
    },
    render: function(){
        return ( ... );
    }
});
```

I've tried a few solutions, and have come to the conclusion that I need to define my own callback on the JSON file like so:

**JSON:**

```
handleData({
    "data": "hello World"
})
```

Is there a way for the `handleData` callback to be defined in the react component, or the response accessed from the react component? Any thoughts as to how I can get this to work are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an odd way to do things, especially the part where you're using jQuery. That's a client-side utility to overcome not knowing where everything is and not having direct access to your elements. It makes no sense to use it when you're using React weith Webpack for bundling: React already knows where everything is (using `refs`) and Webpack means you can just use regular universal Node modules for everything that you need to do.

I'd recommend using something like, using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or a similar universal fetch API:

```
// loadData.js
var request = require('request');
var loadData = function(urlYouNeed, handler) {
  request(urlYouNeed, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      return handler(error, false);
    }

    // do anything processing you need on the body,
    var data = process(body);
    handler(false, data);
};
```

So: just a module you can require in any component you define with `require('./loadData')`. And then in your actual component you do this:

```
var loadData = require('./loadData');
var AppComponent = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      jsonURL: "cdn://whateverjson.json"
    };
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    loadData(this.props.jsonURL, this.updateData);
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },
  updateData: function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    data = secondaryEnsureRightFormat(data);
    this.setState({ data: data });
  },
  render: function(){
    var actualThings = this.state.data.map((entry, pos) => {
      return <Whatever content={entry} key={entry.dontUseThePosVariableUpThere}/>
    });
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        {actualThings}
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Much cleaner.

Comment: This worked great! I'm still new to the nodejs space and had not known about request. Seems to have added a significant amount of resources to my webpack javascript file, though :-/ 

Do you know if there a way that I can use this in a dev environment also? 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: if you use Node, npmjs.com is pretty much where all the good stuff happens. The error you're seeing means that the URL you're calling has been set up with additional security when it comes to other sites using its files. You might have to check the CDN's docs to see how you can access the file for localhost testing. Also if your bundle gets too big, you can always try some other, simpler, fetch libraries ("superagent" is another popular one), or you can even write your own but that's usually not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question, you only have to change your  loadData this way :

```
loadData: function() {
    var c = this
    jQuery.getJSON(jsonFile.json?callback=?)
    .done(function(data) {
        c.handleData(data)
    });
},

handleData: function(data) {
    /* Implement here the function to handle the data */
},
```

Comment: I still get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleData is not defined`

Comment: Have you really defined handleData and called it through c instead of this ? This is a very very common scheme with React and I use it everyday without any trouble :). By the way the bind(this) is useless so I'll just remove it.

Comment: Yes, I'm still seeing that the callback is undefined :-(

Comment: How exactly are you calling the loadData function ? The proper way would be to call it in componentDidMount. Can you update your code to show how you intend to call it ?